# same method to get connection from DB but takes different time in visualvm

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I have one method which get connection from database. I run profiler using visualvm. I found out that the very first time I called method which is to get connection from databse takes longer than the rest.

How to avoid getting database connection multiple times?

Comment: What DB framework  you choose? hibernate or mybatis or others? You can try to use DBConnectionPool.

Comment: my db is mssql 2008

Comment: ok.. Get more information from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html

Comment: you gave me information about mysql. Mine is Microsoft SQL

Comment: oh,sorry,my fault. But the design idea is similar. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

Comment: ur example is for java servlet. Mine is only java program in which I tried to get connection with database. So far I find out that connection pool are used only for application server? It's not advisable to use connection pool for java application which needs to get connection multiple times from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doesn't matter with `java servlet` or `java program` or `application server`, it is just a design idea.
Here is a simple demo, i use MySQL ,hope to explain this design idea:

Class MyConnection:

```
package mysql;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class MyConnection {

    private Connection connection;

    private boolean isUsed;

    public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public void setUsed(boolean isUsed) {
        this.isUsed = isUsed;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public boolean isUsed() {
        return isUsed;
    }

}
```

Class MyConnectionPool:

```
 package mysql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyConnectionPool {
    //this pool will hold the connection 
    static List<MyConnection> connectionPool = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyConnectionPool() {
        String mysqlConfigString = "jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/dbname?user=username&password=password";
        int size = 0;
        while (size++ < 10) {
            Connection conn;
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlConfigString);
                MyConnection myConnection = new MyConnection();
                myConnection.setConnection(conn);
                myConnection.setUsed(false);
                connectionPool.add(myConnection);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public MyConnection getConnection(){
        for (MyConnection myConnection : connectionPool) {
            if(myConnection.isUsed()){
                System.out.println("connection is used");
                continue;
            }
            myConnection.setUsed(true);
            return myConnection;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Class test:

```
package mysql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MysqlTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        MyConnectionPool pool = new MyConnectionPool();

        // connection one
        MyConnection myConnection = pool.getConnection();
        Connection conn = myConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) as co from asset");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getString("co"));
        ps.close();

        // connection tow
        myConnection = pool.getConnection();
        conn = myConnection.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) as co from asset");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getString("co"));

        // connection three
        myConnection = pool.getConnection();
        conn = myConnection.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) as co from asset");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getString("co"));
        //reset connection use status
        myConnection.setUsed(false);

        // re-use connection three
        myConnection = pool.getConnection();
        conn = myConnection.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) as co from asset");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getString("co"));
    }

}
```

Because i never close the `connection` in `MyConnectionPool`, so i can re-use the `connection`.

It is very simple demo. Real Connection Pool is very Complex.
You can find some Connection Pool jar.

I don't know what ORM framework you choose, the popular ORM framework all support Database Connection Pool.